# How to use javascript library amCharts with Dart?

Tags: javascript, charts, dart

I want to draw graphs from amCharts library in Dart.

I transformed a code example from amCharts website in Dart following guidelines described here https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/ but I can not get a chart to be drawn.

I am using Dart editor on mac os.

Everything runs fine when I run the dart app but the chart does not appear.

Does anobydy already tried to use amCharts with Dart?

Comment: Could you paste the code you tried ?

Comment: You answered my question before I could read this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a dart version of [the Js code](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/TQxYB/) of [Simple pie chart](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/pie/).

```dart
import 'dart:js';

main(){
  final chartData = /* same datas as JS */;
  context['AmCharts'].callMethod('ready', [(){
    final chart = new JsObject(context['AmCharts']['AmPieChart']);
    chart['dataProvider'] = new JsObject.jsify(chartData);
    chart['titleField'] = "country";
    chart['valueField'] = "litres";
    chart['outlineColor'] = "#FFFFFF";
    chart['outlineAlpha'] = 0.8;
    chart['outlineThickness'] = 2;
    chart['balloonText'] = "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>";

    // WRITE
    chart.callMethod('write', ["chartdiv"]);
  }]);
}
```

Basically :

- use array notation when in Js you use properties.
- use [callMethod](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js/JsObject.html#callMethod) when in Js you call methods.
- use [new JsObject](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js/JsObject.html#) to create new js objects.
- use [new JsObject.jsify](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js/JsObject.html#jsify) to convert JSON-like structure.

Comment: What html file would you use with this piece of dart? I get it that there should be a <div id="chartdiv"></div> but what about the <script> ?

Comment: Something like `<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script type="application/dart" src="myEntryPoint.dart"></script>
<script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>`

Comment: Do not forget to set the size of the div element :)

Comment: Both of you helped me: I did not know how to call the "ready" method and I had forgotten the style/height part of the div element.